# When using the Vue-Router [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I am starting on Vue, or using the router vue I have identified the following error that is below, I am thinking that it is something related to autentica, what do you think?

My Routes stay here

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'landing-page',
      component: require('@/components/LandingPage'),
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard-page',
      component: require('@/components/Dashboard').default,
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/',
    },
  ],
});
```

My Html stay here

```
<template>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="navigation__active"><router-view to="/"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Home</router-view></li>
        <li class="navigation__active"><router-view to="/dashboard"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Dashboard</router-view></li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

This Error

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <MenuPage> at src\renderer\components\Menu.vue
         <DesktopSmf> at src\renderer\App.vue
           <Root>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's `router-link` not `router-view` when you want to create a link. `router-view` is the block which the content of the link goes into.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, PICK an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's `router-link` not `router-view` when you want to create a link. `router-view` is the block which the content of the link goes into, and it must be in your `App.vue`.

So this should work in your `Menu.vue`:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="navigation__active"><router-link to="/"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Home</router-link></li>
    <li class="navigation__active"><router-link to="/dashboard"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Dashboard</router-link></li>
</ul>
```

and in your `App.vue` template you must have a line going similar like

```
<router-view />
```